# Texshop is not typesetting my document but I don't understand why

Tags: errors

[image: Error message]

This is the beginning of my document. I have typeset it fine before, I don't understand why it isn't working now.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}          
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[loose,nice]{units} %replace "nice" by "ugly" for units in upright fractions
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand*\chem[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{tikz} % <--- added
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,         % <--- added
                chains,              % <--- added
                decorations.markings,% <--- added
                positioning,         % <--- added
                quotes,              % <--- added
                }





 \begin{document}


\title{Exercise 3: Production of Maleic Anhydride}

\author{Sophie Parsons%
  \thanks{CRSid: \texttt{xxx}}}
\affil{uni}
```

Comment: Try to enter "s" and return.

Comment: perfect thank you!! what is the reason behind this??

Comment: You are very welcome. Good look on your project. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enter "s" and return (this option is written on your screenshot in grey). Then try to compile your project a second time.

I am not an expert, but basically an error of some has had occurred and this misbehaviour sometimes corruptes some auxiliary files. The "s" just tells to compiler to try to run anyway and ignore all errors. If the error is not a fatal one, the project will most likely compile partially and the new auxiliary files are not corrupted. Sometimes it is necessary to delete all auxiliary files.

By the way, your MWE is most likely incomplete.